# Any off-line tool for iOS app sales analytics?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Anyone aware of tool to analyze sales report downloaded from iTunesConnect -> Sales & Trends -> Sales -> Download? This is basically formatted text file with columns. I'm not asking for software which will log in to my account and retrieve data - I don't trust them. Something which I can do locally and which will show me stats per country, etc...

Comment: I hope someone has an answer better than download the spreadsheets and run them through Numbers or Excel. However, you might read the blog of Craig Hockenberry that detailed how much [engineering work and testing went into AppVis](http://furbo.org/2013/11/19/appviz-wtf/) which would be my choice for the job at hand - even with your strong preference for a solution with a different architecture.

Comment: Before reading that article I would mention that there are number of ASO services like MobileHQ, Sensor Tower, etc... Somehow if you pay them, they got data which Apple is not releasing and the only way I can think of is such services may successfully capture data from provided itunesconnect accounts and sell to them. There might be something in article to prove otherwise, but it might be dirty games over there.